# GitLab API - retrieve repository files

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-api

I have the following GitLab structure

```
Project-X
   - Repository-1
        - FileFoder-A
             - File-1
             - File-2
        - File-3
   - Repository-2
        - FileFoder-B
             - File-1
             - File-2
        - File-3
```

I am trying to fetch all files under `Project-X`/`Repository-A` using GitLab API v4.

I have tried the following:

`https://gitlab.xx.local/api/v4/<project-x-id>/repository/<repository-A-id>/archive`

But, it returns a `404`.

Comment: `Project-X` is a group ? Also, you specify `archive` in your request but there is no file named `archive` in your repository. Ref il also missing.

Comment: @NicolasPepinster, Project-X is a project in a group. I believe the archive was to retrieve the contents in tgz format. 
I tried with ref=master. But still the same result.

Comment: @NicolasPepinster even without the archive, it returns 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion with the project structure. GitLab has a one to one relationship between projects and repositories. It's not possible that 'Project-X' has two repositories. Maybe you have a group with multiple projects?

In any case, the API endpoint is not quite right, either. It should be something like `https://gitlab.xx.local/api/v4/projects/<project-x-id>/archive`. See [GitLab API documentation for the repository file archive endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#get-file-archive) for more details.

Comment: When i do an `api/v4/projects/<project-id>/tree`, I can see all the directories under this project. But how can I get all the files of a specific directory under this project?

Comment: Is there any difference between a repo and a directory in Git? 
I can see from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#get-file-archive - `Get a list of repository files and directories in a project.`

Comment: Files and directories are *in* a Git repository.